# Function contains infinite loops, and it seems everything is ok

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I wrote function, that input array is list of intervals and returns nonoverlapping intervals.
Here is the function:

```
def mergeOverlappingIntervals(intervals):
    new=[]
    i=0
    while i <len(intervals):    
        if intervals[i][1]<intervals[i+1][0]:
            new.append(intervals[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            p1=i
            p2=i
            while intervals[i][1]<=intervals[i+1][0]:
              i+=1
              p2+=1
            new.append([intervals[p1][0],intervals[p2][1]])
            i=p2
    return new
```

but this function contains infinite loops. It is unclear to me, why this function contains infinite loops and does not get expected outputs.
Example of inputs:

```
interval=[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 5],
    [4, 7],
    [6, 8],
    [9, 10]
  ]

outputs=[
  [1, 2],
  [3, 8],
  [9, 10]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: is it unclear to you why it works? also your code doesn't necessarily contain infinite loops, `while` loops just loop _while the condition evaluates to `True`_ (hence the name `while`), so if at some point the condition evaluates to `False`, the looping stops. It is unclear to me what is unclear to you.

Comment: @Matiiss but this code contains somehow infinite loops. You can try with my example. For me unclear is, why this code contains infinite loop

Comment: `intervals` never gets shorter, but `i` isn't necessarily incremented on every iteration. Namely, if `intervals[i][1] >= intervals[i+1][0]` and `intervals[i][1] > intervals[i+1][0]`. Thus `i < len(intervals)` will stay true forever.

Comment: You should make your question clearer. As it is written, it looks like your code gives the expected output and that you don't understand how while loops can stop running at some point. Make it clear that you run into some infinite loop and *don't* get any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner while loop uses the wrong condition. You want to merge two intervals when `intervals[i][1]` is *greater than or equal to*, not less than or equal to, `intervals[i+1][0]`.

```
while intervals[i][1] >= intervals[i+1][0]:
    i += 1
    p2 += 1
```

There may be other issues, but this one stands out as the primary problem.